# How to select multiple nodes in different levels?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Having this (simplified) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
<Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Poly 1</name>
            <Polygon>
                        <coordinates>
                            -58.40844625779582,-34.60295278618136,0
                        </coordinates>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Poly 2</name>
            <Polygon>
                        <coordinates>
                            -58.40414334150432,-34.59992445476809,0
                        </coordinates>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

How can I select the name and coordinates of each Placemark?
Right now I can select their name with the following XPath expression:

```
//Document//Placemark//name
```

How can I select both without any other data?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use a union in your XPath expression. Just use the operator: `|`

```
//Document/Placemark/name | //Document/Placemark/Polygon/coordinates
```

Don't use the `//` (*descendant* axis) if you don't need to. Using `//`, this would also work: `//name | //coordinates`. It's better performance-wise to specify the exact path.

Comment: Is there a simplification that avoids repeating `//Document/Placemark/`?

Answer (score 6):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/Placemark/name | /*/*/Placemark/*/coordinates
```

This specifies the *union* of the results of two separate XPath expressions -- the standard XPath union operator `|` is used. Selected are all `name` elements that are children of a `Placemark` element that is a grandchild of the top element of the XML document, *plus* all `coordinates` elements that are grand-children of a `Placemark` element that is a grandchild of the top element of the XML document.

The selected elements come in document order (although no normative W3C document specifies the order), which means that in the result of the evaluation (usually of type XmlNodeList) any `name` element is directly followed by its corresponding `coordinates` element.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: //Placemark/*[self::name or descendant::coordinates]