# Regular expression in Selenium xpath to select different table row

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath

I have two possible xpaths on which I can find the solution. Is there a way with regex so that I can combine the 2 possible xpath in a single xpath string?

Comment: What kind of a regex do you want to use? Can you tell which `tr` contains the data by something other than the index? If it's just the index, you can use the `position()` function in a predicate. `tr[position() = 6 or position() = 7]`

Comment: For example that I am testing the value of a textbox which might be present in 3rd row or the 6th row of the table. So for the indexing of the tr tag is there any regular expression that can be embedded in the  xpath?

Comment: You could see if the `position()` of the `tr` tag representing the row is equal to 3 or 6, as explained above. I don't know of any way to do it with a regular expression. As for your updated question, it is possible to combine multiple XPath expression into a single one. Take a look at [this answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11040630/1407656)

Comment: Css selectors may be a solution rather then xpath as they support nth-of-type. Without seeing your HTML, it is impossible to offer a concrete answer

Comment: Thanks a ton Tom. That really helped me alot. I wanted a sort of OR condition between 2 xpath and it should also be combined into a single xpath string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [or operator in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes).

For instance, this will find all book or all chapter nodes:

```
//book|//chapter
```

In general to `or` two nodesets with query_a and query_b just do:

```
query_a|query_b
```